# 'No suitable driver' error Android mySql

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am trying to connect to a online mySql database in android program.
this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

     ImageView image;
     TextView text;
     URL url;
     Bitmap bmp;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         dB();
}

public void dB() {
    String username = "user";
    String password = "pass";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://sql8.freemysqlhosting.net:3306";

    Statement stmt = null;
    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection db = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://sql8.freemysqlhosting.net:3306" +"user=user&password=pass");
        Log.d("SQL Connection","open");

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("SQL Error","" + e.getMessage());
    }

    }
}
```

The problem is with the connection line.
I mean that the Java recognize the 'mySql connector' file.
I am using

> mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga

The problem is that while running their is error:

> 06-14 10:07:39.868 19021-19021/com.example.desktopa.outbox_sim2 E/SQL Error: No suitable driver

I searched in the documentation, but i found nothing.
What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was need to change the `getConnection` function to(with commas):

```
DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
```